# Why is my website failing to upload to my database (using MySQLI) and then not redirecting me?

Tags: php

I've been racking my brains over this problem for a while now but as yet have not found the problem. I have a form (in index.php) that uploads the user input to a database after the submit button is pressed. As expected I'm redirected to add_records.php after pressing submit, but then I'm stuck on it, despite including the line

```
header("location: index.php")
```

The redirect works fine if I comment out all the mysqli code, therefore I've concluded the error is to do with mysqli and uploading to the database (perhaps I'm handling the geographical data incorrectly). I've done all the usual things - checked the error log, checked for any errors on PHPMyAdmin but all show no errors! I shown the code below to help troubleshoot, with all sensitive info replaced with '#' (note - I've checked the database password etc. several times and they're correct).

index.php:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: ##/records/login.php");
    exit;
}

echo file_get_contents("##/code/header.php");
?>
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Hi, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></b>. Welcome to our site.</h1>
</div>
<form action="##/records/add_records.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="species" placeholder="Species">
    <br>
    <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
    <br>
    <input type="time" name="time" placeholder="Time">
    <br>
    <input type="location" name="location" placeholder="Location Name">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lat/long" placeholder="Lat Long">
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="count" placeholder="Count">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="county" placeholder="County (default Norfolk)">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country (default United Kingdom)">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Notes">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<p>
    <a href="##/records/logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Out of Your Account</a>
</p>
<?php echo file_get_contents("##/code/footer.php"); ?>
```

add_records.php:

```
<?php include_once '##/records/config_bird_records.php';

    $species = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['species']);
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date']);
    $time = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['time']);
    $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['location']);
    $latlong = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['latlong']);
    $count = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['count']);
    $county = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['county']);
    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['country']);
    $notes = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['notes']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO bird_db (Species, Date, Time, Location, Lat/Long, Count, County, Country, Notes) VALUES ('$species', $date, $time, '$location', geography::STGeomFromText('POINT($latlong)', 4326), $count, '$county', '$country', '$notes')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close($conn);

    header("location: ##/records/index.php")
?>
```

config_bird_records.php:

```
<?php
/* Database credentials.*/
define('DB_SERVER', '##');
define('DB_USERNAME', '##');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '##');
define('DB_NAME', '##');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($conn === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Thanks for any help,
Louis

Comment: Have you try to use header on success query ? header isn't already sent? please learn how to use prepare stmt (Sql Inject)

Answer (score 1):

The `header` method [needs to be called](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) before you send any output to the browser.

Your code includes output in both success and error cases, which means the redirect will never work. If you remove  `echo "Records added successfully.";` it should work.

Comment: I removed the if else statement completely but I still have the same problem :( I'll admit, I'm not at all a PHP expert so maybe I've missed something simple

Comment: Please post the updated code in the question. Is there any white space in add_records.php before the <? tag?

Comment: I've now updated the code in the original post. Also, I just checked and there is no whitespace before the <? tag in add_records.php

Comment: The new code you've posted doesn't insert anything into the database. What happens when you run this code - what do you see in the browser?

Comment: Oops, I've now updated the code again! It was interesting though as I still got had the same issue, even after removing the code that inserts the data to the database. The issue must be elsewhere in the file then.

Comment: I just tried commenting out every line in add_records.php except the database config (the first line), the line that closes the database connection and the 'header' that redirects the user but I still had the same problem. Perhaps the error lies in config_bird_records.php.

Comment: Please tell us what actually happens when you submit the form, ideally by using Developer Tools in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript for that instead of header() fro redirecting; function
try the following:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Upload Successful');
            window.location='redirected_page.php';
            </script>";
```

As for the failing to upload, have you googled how mysqli_real_escape_string works, u need to because it will affect some special characters in you variables

Comment: Thanks for the help. What's the benefit of using the javascript instead?